# Kotlin scanner - validate nextLine() user input

Tags: kotlin, java.util.scanner

first of all sorry for the title, couldn't think of anything else.
I'm currently finishing a project on JetBrains Hyperskill, the project is a unit converter where the user can convert weight, length and temperature units. I'm almost finished with the project, the conversion works fine, however I have a problem with user input.

I have an enum class that holds all units -
[image: enum class Units]

The user input is made out of following parts:

```
  <number> + 
    <(unit name) or (degree + unit name) or (degrees + unit name)> +
    <random word like "to" or "in"> +
    <(unit name) or (degree + unit name) or (degrees + unit name)>
```

So, user can input something like:

- 1 C to F
- 1 Celsius to kelvins

But, also able to input this:

- 1 degree Celsius to kelvins
- 5 degrees Celsius to degrees Fahrenheit

Each input is held in a variable and user types this in a **single line**

- `val amount = scan.toDouble()` - amount to convert
- `val source = scan.nextLine().toUpperCase()`  -  this should read input like “celsius” and “degrees Celsius”
- `val word = scan.next()`  - random word
- `val target = scan.nextLine().toUpperCase()` -   this too should read input like “celsius” and “degrees Celsius”

These are the valid inputs for each unit type:
[image]

My question -
How can I make next() or nextLine() work for both “Fahrenheit” and “degrees Fahrenheit” (valid input), but if the user types something else, error message prints in console like “Parse error”?

[image]

Comment: If I were you, rather than processing multiple inputs, first I'd ask the user the entire sentence and then process it.

Answer (score 2):

Is the "word" token really random? If it's either *to* or *in* then you could split the string on that, and then you'll have

```
<value> <source units>, <target units>
```

You could also use a regex if you know how to wrangle those, something like this

```
(\d+) (degree \w+|degrees \w+|\w+) \w+ (.+)
```

where you have each part you care about in a capturing group.

Or, for this case, you could just do a string replace on `degrees`  and `degree`  with a blank string to remove them (in that order, so you don't end up with random `s` characters) - you don't care about the word, and once you do that everything looks like `value unit word unit` and you can split them on spaces and process each token.

You have a few options! Also don't post code screenshots pls, paste it in - not everyone can read them

Comment: Thanks, will try that out! Also, will keep in mind about the screenshots